# Como posso tirar print da tela em segundo plano com Python

Tags: python, print, tela

Gostaria de poder realizar screenshot, da aplicação rodando em segundo plano com o Python.
Em cada tela que a aplicação entrar, eu preciso de um print.
Consegui fazer, com o pyautogui. Mas, ele só tira screenshot da tela principal, quando deixo a aplicação rodando em segundo plano, só recebo os print da tela em que estou e não da aplicação que está rodando.

````
nomeArquivo = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%M-%d_%H%M%S' + '.png') #nome e formato do arquivo.
foto = pyautogui.screenshot() #foto sendo salva.
foto.save('C:\ProjetosPython\Testes\Evidências/' + nomeArquivo) #caminho onde salvo a foto.```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no seu `cron` vc tem q utilizar o `export DISPLAY=:0`
segue um exemplo:

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0; /usr/bin/python3 script.py
```

lembrando que o valor do display tem q ser o display ativo. na maioria das vezes é o 0. e precisa ser executado pelo cron do usuário em que a sessão esta iniciada. não pode ser root.

segunda alternativa é utilizar o `scrot`

como instalar: https://www.tecmint.com/take-screenshots-in-linux-using-scrot/

ex no cron:

```
* * * * * DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/scrot "/home/user/Desktop/screenshots/$(date +'\%d-\%m-\%Y \%T').png"
```

mesma coisa tem q por no cron do usuario e nao do root.

Comment: Jasar Orion agradeço! Mas, ainda não funcionou.

Comment: estranho fiz os testes aqui no meu pc e funciono ( fiz antes de postar ). tanto é que tenho um sisteminha d monitoramento que roda algo similar e funciona

Comment: vou dar uma pesquisada para ver se consigo te ajudar melhor

Comment: Agradeço pela ajuda e atenção!

Comment: ha uma coisa que eu esqueci: não pode ser no crontab rodando como root. tem q ser no usuário em que a sessão do X esta ativa. acabei de detestar aqui.

Comment: Obrigado, consegui.

Comment: qual dos metodos vc utilizou? marca como resolvido depois

Comment: Utilizei a segunda alternativa `scrot`

Comment: boa. como uso raspberry não tem o scrot pra ela. dai tenho q fazer na mao rsss.